# How can I draw a perfect circle without an enclosing square in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

In Word, I'm trying to draw a circle, that is a perfect circle. When I copy this circle, I only want to copy the circle part. Yet there's always a white square that encloses this circle.

I don't want this! I chose the circle option, because I'm trying to get a circle.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! More details are needed about what you are trying to do with the circle so we can even know if we can help you. Please tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this. It may be helpful to read **[ask]** to improve your question.

Comment: What's your goal?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a circle using autoshapes, the default setting is for the canvas to have zero transparency and the background color to be white.  Right click on it and select `Format AutoShape`.  Set transparancy to 100%.  If you copy the circle and paste it to another place in Word, the copy will also be transparent (only the circle will be visible).

I just did a quick test copying a circle that had transparency set to 100% and pasting that into another application.  I was surprised to find that the transparency survived.  So it looks like that is a pretty universal solution regardless of how you're trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The creation of the square, which I assume is a "drawing canvas", can be turned off in the settings:
**Office button > <kbd>Word options</kbd> > ...**

*(can't check the exact position as I do not have access to word currently)*